# Nested eloquent where clause in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, eloquent

I'm building a small application in `Laravel 5.4` where I'm having models: Interaction and InteractionSummary. Each Interaction can be created by an User and each Interaction summary contain Contact of a Company interacted with. So my following is my models:

**User:**

```
public function interactions()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Interaction');
}
```

**Company:**

```
public function contacts()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Contact', 'company_contact', 'company_id','contact_id');
}
```

**Contact:**

```
public function companies()
{
    return $this
        ->belongsToMany('App\Company', 'company_contact','contact_id', 'company_id')->withTimestamps();
}

public function interactions()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Interaction', 'contact_client_interaction','contact_id', 'interaction_id');
}
```

**Interaction:**

```
public function contactsAssociation()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Contact', 'contact_interaction',  'interaction_id', 'contact_id')->withPivot('company_id')->withTimestamps();
}

public function interactionSummaries()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\InteractionSummary');
}
```

**InteractionSummary**

```
public function interaction()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Interaction');
}

public function client()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Company', 'company_id');
}
```

Now I want to get where clause to find the Company model referred as client in InteractionSummary model and get all meeting summary details of each meeting, so I tried something like this:

```
$user  = Auth::user();
$summaries = $user->interactions() 
                ->whereHas('interactionSummary', function($query){
                    $query->where('client', 'like', '%'.$request->input.'%');
                })->get();
```

It throws error of

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::interactionSummary()

Any suggestions in this are welcome. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accessing relation as `property` returns a `Collection` object.

Access relation as a method will give you a `Builder` object so you can call `whereHas` method on it.

Also: You have `interactionSummaries` relation inside your `Interaction` model not `interactionSummary`.

Try this

```php
$user  = Auth::user();
$summaries = $user->interactions() 
                  ->whereHas('interactionSummaries', function($query) use ($request) {
                      $query->where('client', 'like', '%' . $request->input . '%');
                  })->get();
```

Comment: I guess I'm doing the same.

Comment: @NitishKumar In your question you're doing this `$user->interactions->whereHas`

Comment: I'm getting this `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::interactions()`

Comment: This error indicates that you're calling `interactions()` method on Builder object which means that the `$user` is not `User` model where your `interactions` method is. Please confirm

Comment: Ok I got it, but I'm getting the same for `interactionSummary`, so do I need to create method for that? I mean even if I need to what will be the relationship?

Comment: @NitishKumar what error are you getting? and please update your question with your modified code.

Comment: Updated. Please review.

Comment: I've updated the answer, though you guided me very well. Thanks.

Comment: @NitishKumar Glad to help you :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
$summaries = $user->interactions
                ->whereHas('interactionSummary', function($query) use($request){
                    $query->where('client', 'like', '%'.$request->input.'%');
                })->get();
```

Comment: This ain't helping me out, I've already checked by removing request and passing an empty string. It happens to be the same.

Comment: @NitishKumar Ok let me check it